# How to implement minimum and maximum validation for a specific amount of items in a stored procedure in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to add some validation so the minimum amount of items is greater or equal to 2 and the maximum number of items is less than or equal to 10 in my stored procedure. If the items are less than 2 or greater than 10 I would like an error message to display and for the procedure to not execute. If the items are within the validation then the stored procedure should execute as normal.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_new_order
(
    p_order_id    IN ORDERS.ORDER_ID%TYPE, 
    p_order_num   IN ORDERS.ORDER_NUMBER%TYPE,
    p_name        IN ORDERS.BILLING_NAME%TYPE,
    p_email       IN ORDERS.BILLING_EMAIL%TYPE,
    p_address     IN ORDERS.BILLING_ADDRESS%TYPE,
    p_city        IN ORDERS.BILLING_CITY%TYPE,
    p_province    IN ORDERS.BILLING_PROVINCE%TYPE,
    p_postcode    IN ORDERS.BILLING_POSTCODE%TYPE,
    p_telephone   IN ORDERS.BILLING_TELEPHONE%TYPE, 
    p_total       IN ORDERS.BILLING_TOTAL%TYPE,
    p_order_date  IN ORDERS.ORDER_DATE%TYPE,
    p_items       IN ORDERS.ITEMS%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert attempted');

    INSERT INTO orders (
      order_id,
      order_number,
      billing_name,
      billing_email,
      billing_address,
      billing_city,
      billing_province,
      billing_postcode,
      billing_telephone,
      billing_total,
      order_date,
      items
    ) VALUES (
      p_order_id,
      p_order_num,
      p_name,
      p_email,
      p_address,
      p_city,
      p_province,
      p_postcode,
      p_telephone,
      p_total,
      p_order_date,
      p_items
    );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert succeeded');

    EXCEPTION
     WHEN others THEN   
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Insert rejected');
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Code:  ' || SQLCODE);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('SQL Error Message:  ' || SQLERRM); 
      ROLLBACK;
END;
/
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_item AS object(
    order_id INT, 
    product_id INT,
    seller_id INT, 
    sub_order_number CHAR(10),
    quantity INT, 
    condition CHAR(10),
    unit_price NUMBER, 
    cost_charge NUMBER,
    total NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE order_items AS Table of order_item;
/

 CREATE TABLE orders (
    order_id INT CONSTRAINT PKEY_order PRIMARY KEY,
    order_number CHAR(10),
    billing_name CHAR(100),
    billing_email CHAR(100),
    billing_address VARCHAR2(100),
    billing_city VARCHAR2(100),
    billing_province VARCHAR2(100),
    billing_postcode VARCHAR2(100),
    billing_telephone CHAR(25),
    billing_total NUMBER,
    order_date DATE,
    Items order_items)
    Nested Table Items Store As Orders_Item
  /
```

Comment: Don't catch the `OTHERS` exception; just let the query fail and it will implicitly `ROLLBACK` and the error will be output.

Comment: Are you expecting the validation on each row of the `order_item.quantity` (you must order between 2 and 10 of each item but can order as many items as you want) column or on the `orders.items` column (you must order between 2 and 10 items but can order whatever quantity of those items you want) or on the total `order_item.quantity` for each order (you must order items so that the total quantity of those items is between 2 and 10)?

Comment: @MT0 I would want the validation for the `Items` column which is a nested table that produces an array of items. So ideally I would like it to check to see if the items in the array are greater or equal to 2 or less than and equal to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am hopeful that this is a homework question.  If this is a real system, there are several things that don't make sense-- having a nested table for order items would be hugely problematic in a real system, disallowing an order that happens to consist of a single item is silly, etc.

In your procedure, you can check the number of elements in the collection as the first step of the procedure and raise a custom error

```
IF NOT( p_items.count BETWEEN 2 and 10 )
THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR( -20001, 'Orders must have between 2 and 10 items.  This order has ' || p_items.count );
END IF;
```

You'd almost certainly want to remove the exception handler.  As @MT0 points out, a `when others` exception handler that just calls `dbms_output.put_line` is hugely problematic.  You can't assume that anyone will ever see messages written to the `dbms_output` buffer-- the vast majority of real systems won't do anything with that text.  If you raise the exception, the transaction will automatically be rolled back.

Comment: This is a homework task and not used for a real system. Where do I put this if statement? Just before the insert? Sure will do, it's something we've been taught didn't know it has it's disadvantages.

Comment: @Jal - In theory you could put the check anywhere but like I said in the answer, it generally makes sense to have validations as the first step of the procedure (immediately after the `begin`).  No sense doing the insert if the data is invalid.